# CSS float divs left to right underneath each other

Tags: html, css

I want to float my divs left to right underneath  each other sort of like this:

```
1
   2
3 
   4
```

But what I get is:

```
1  2
3  4
```

Does anyone know how to do this properly? thanks

Comment: Please post your HTML and CSS.

Comment: They're the exact same thing in your question. Can you elaborate?

Comment: check this out: [all-about-floats](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a wrapper div and let the inner divs touch each other just a fragment:

HTML:

```
<div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body > div {
    background: lightgreen;
    width: 99px;
    overflow: auto;
}
div > div {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
div > div:nth-child(2n-1) {
    background: lightyellow;
    float: left;
}
div > div:nth-child(2n) {
    background: lightblue;
    float: right;
}
```

[**And a demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/rzmdJ/)

Answer (score 3):

the div you floated left, do a clear:right; AND the div you floated right do a clear:left;

should work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<div style="float:left;">1</div>
<div style="clear:left;"></div>

<div style="float:right;">2</div>
<div style="clear:right;"></div>

<div style="float:left;">3</div>
<div style="clear:left;"></div>

<div style="float:right;">4</div>
<div style="clear:right;"></div>
```

Comment: It is correct. The element that it's nested in on JS fiddle is just a lot wider.

Comment: A lot of unneeded `div` and `br`...

Comment: Not really? Do you have a better solution?

Comment: Yes, for instance check the answer of Rob White or Kolink...

Comment: I suppose the <br /> tags could be gotten rid of. But, the float seems like a better solution than the margin. And if you're using floats, it's essential to clear after each div.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using `float`, consider using `margin`:

For instance, assuming your HTML is:

```
<div id="zigzag">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>
```

Then your CSS would be:

```css
#zigzag>* {width:50%}
#zigzag>:nth-child(even) {margin-left:auto}
```

Comment: I ended up using clears for right and left but this also works well